# Calling sp_cursoropen with Linked Server Throws Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We recently moved a database to it's own SQL Server which broke a call to a stored proc wrapped in a `sp_cursoropen` statement.

The original call, which **worked**, was to a database on the same server as the calling database:

```sql
using database1
exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output, N'exec database2.dbo.sp_mystoredproc 1234'
```

We had to move the second database to its own server for compliance reasons and created a linked server between the two. We changed the call to:

```
using database1
exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output, N'exec LinkedDBServer.database2.dbo.sp_mystoredproc 1234'
```

The call **no longer works** and gives us two errors

> A server cursor cannot be opened on the given statement or statements. Use a default result set or client cursor.
>   The cursor was not declared

**The funny thing** is that running the stored proc command on it's own **works** and returns rows of data:

```
using database1
exec LinkedDBServer1.database2.dbo.sp_mystoredproc 1234
```

**Also funny,** putting direct SQL from the stored proc itself and pasting it in place of sp_mystoredproc also **works**, even with the cursor:

```
using database1
exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output, N'Select * from LinkedDBServer1.Dbname.dbo.sometable where sometable.id = 1234'
```

This leads me to believe that the return type of the stored procedure that runs via a linked server is somehow different than that of the same stored procedure running on the same SQL server as the calling database. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation to support my hypothesis.

**Does anyone know why a stored procedure that returns rows of data wouldn't play well with sp_cursoropen when a linked server is involved?**

Note: I'm not interested in workarounds. I know there are many ways to fix this such as writing to a temp table first, using a different service to grab the data or some other method of completing the task. I'm only interested in what low level difference in the SQL server is causing this error even though the separate pieces being called to through the linked server work independently.